# d3.js parallel coordinate with one different scale

Tags: d3.js, coordinates, scale, parallel-coordinates

I'm trying to generate a parallel coordinate using d3.js
My problem is that the first scale should display different strings.

with the original code it looks like this:
[image]

and with my test it looks like this (no lines):
[image]
the error code is:

> Error: Invalid value for  attribute d="M33,NaNL99,161.37817638266068L165,6.543121881682145L231,16.962488563586458L297,180"

here is my code:

```
function parallelChart (id, size) {

  if(size == 'small') {
    var margin = {top: 20, right: 80, bottom: 30, left: 50},
        width = 460 - margin.left - margin.right,
        height = 230 - margin.top - margin.bottom;
  } else {
    var margin = {top: 20, right: 80, bottom: 30, left: 50},
        width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
        height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;
  }

  var x = d3.scale.ordinal().rangePoints([0, width], 1),
      y = {},
      dragging = {};

  var line = d3.svg.line(),
      axis = d3.svg.axis().orient("left"),
      background,
      foreground;

  var svg = d3.select(id).append("svg")
    .attr("class", 'center-block')
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

  // Original
  d3.csv("dataNew.csv", function(error, healthdata) {
    x.domain(dimensions = d3.keys(healthdata[0]).filter(function(d) {
      return d != "Datum" && (y[d] = d3.scale.linear()
        .domain(d3.extent(healthdata, function(p) { return +p[d]; }))
        .range([height, 0]));
    }));

    // this did not work
    // d3.csv("dataNew.csv", function(error, healthdata) {
    //   x.domain(dimensions = d3.keys(healthdata[0]).filter(function(d) {
    //     if(d == "Datum") {
    //       return d == "Datum" && ( (y[d] = d3.time.scale()
    //         .domain(d3.extent(healthdata, function(p) { return +p[d]; }))
    //         .range([height, 0])));
    //     }
    //     return d != "Datum" && ( (y[d] = d3.scale.linear()
    //       .domain(d3.extent(healthdata, function(p) { return +p[d]; }))
    //       .range([height, 0])));                  
    //   }));

      // Add grey background lines for context.
      background = svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "background")
      .selectAll("path")
        .data(healthdata)
      .enter().append("path")
        .attr("d", path);

      // Add blue foreground lines for focus.
      foreground = svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "foreground")
      .selectAll("path")
        .data(healthdata)
      .enter().append("path")
        .attr("d", path);

      // Add a group element for each dimension.
      var g = svg.selectAll(".dimension")
        .data(dimensions)
      .enter().append("g")
        .attr("class", "dimension")
        .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + x(d) + ")"; })
        .call(d3.behavior.drag()
          .origin(function(d) { return {x: x(d)}; })
          .on("dragstart", function(d) {
            dragging[d] = x(d);
            background.attr("visibility", "hidden");
          })
          .on("drag", function(d) {
            dragging[d] = Math.min(width, Math.max(0, d3.event.x));
            foreground.attr("d", path);
            dimensions.sort(function(a, b) { return position(a) - position(b); });
            x.domain(dimensions);
            g.attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + position(d) + ")"; })
          })
          .on("dragend", function(d) {
            delete dragging[d];
            transition(d3.select(this)).attr("transform", "translate(" + x(d) + ")");
            transition(foreground).attr("d", path);
            background
                .attr("d", path)
              .transition()
                .delay(500)
                .duration(0)
                .attr("visibility", null);
          }));

    // Add an axis and title.
    g.append("g")
      .attr("class", "axis")
      .each(function(d) { d3.select(this).call(axis.scale(y[d])); })
      .append("text")
      .style("text-anchor", "middle")
      .attr("y", -9)
      .text(function(d) { return d; });

    // Add and store a brush for each axis.
    g.append("g")
      .attr("class", "brush")
      .each(function(d) {
        d3.select(this).call(y[d].brush = d3.svg.brush().y(y[d]).on("brushstart", brushstart).on("brush", brush));
      })
      .selectAll("rect")
      .attr("x", -8)
      .attr("width", 16);
  });

  function position(d) {
    var v = dragging[d];
    return v == null ? x(d) : v;
  }

  function transition(g) {
    return g.transition().duration(500);
  }

  // Returns the path for a given data point.
  function path(d) {
    return line(dimensions.map(function(p) { return [position(p), y[p](d[p])]; }));
  }

  function brushstart() {
    d3.event.sourceEvent.stopPropagation();
  }

  // Handles a brush event, toggling the display of foreground lines.
  function brush() {
    var actives = dimensions.filter(function(p) { return !y[p].brush.empty(); }),
        extents = actives.map(function(p) { return y[p].brush.extent(); });
    foreground.style("display", function(d) {
      return actives.every(function(p, i) {
        return extents[i][0] <= d[p] && d[p] <= extents[i][1];
      }) ? null : "none";
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here goes one example where the author manage string and numbers in the same parallel coord:

http://bl.ocks.org/syntagmatic/4020926

Create an array of dimensions that will be further used...

```
var dimensions = [
  {
    name: "name",
    scale: d3.scale.ordinal().rangePoints([0, height]),
    type: "string"
  },
  {
    name: "economy (mpg)",
    scale: d3.scale.linear().range([0, height]),
    type: "number"
  },
...
]
```

...before load the data, define the domains by mapping your previous **dimensions** definition...

```
var x = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .domain(dimensions.map(function(d) { return d.name; }))
    .rangePoints([0, width]);
```

...define a variable **dimension** *(pay attention, dimensions != dimension)* with the locations of each axis...

```
var dimension = svg.selectAll(".dimension")
    .data(dimensions)
    .enter().append("g")
    .attr("class", "dimension")
    .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + x(d.name) +    ")"; });
```

...once the data is loaded, execute a for each to define the domain of each dimension...

```
d3.csv("cars.small.csv", function(data) {

  dimensions.forEach(function(dimension) {
    dimension.scale.domain(dimension.type === "number"
        ? d3.extent(data, function(d) { return +d[dimension.name]; })
        : data.map(function(d) { return d[dimension.name]; }).sort());
  });

...
}
```

... axis lines and foreground are still loaded in the same way...

```
svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "background")
      .selectAll("path")
      .data(data)
      .enter().append("path")
      .attr("d", draw);

  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "foreground")
      .selectAll("path")
      .data(data)
      .enter().append("path")
      .attr("d", draw);
```

... this code will load the text of each axis, observe that it is now using properties from the **dimensions** that we defined in the beggining.

```
    dimension.append("g")
          .attr("class", "axis")
          .each(function(d) { d3.select(this).call(yAxis.scale(d.scale)); })
          .append("text")
          .attr("class", "title")
          .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
          .attr("y", -9)
          .text(function(d) { return d.name; });
```

that`s all =).